# Querying WordPress by array size

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a website which allows users to 'like' posts. A post's likes are stored as an array of user IDs in a postmeta field called "likers".

I'm having trouble displaying posts in order of most liked. Ideally I could query the size of the likers array and order by that value, but I can't find a way to do it using WP_Query.

At the moment I'm querying for every post's ID and likers field, then in a foreach loop I'm counting the size of the likers array, sorting by that value and using a custom loop to display each post. Except with this method I can't use the standard WP pagination function.

Has anyone got a better solution?

Here's the current code:

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'likers'", 'ARRAY_A');
if (!$posts) {
    return "No posts found.";
} else {

    // add them to an array with the size of their 'likers' field
    foreach($posts as &$post) {
        $post['likers'] = count(unserialize($post['meta_value']));
    }

    // sort array by likes
    uasort($posts, function ($i, $j) {
        $a = $i['likers'];
        $b = $j['likers'];
        if ($a == $b) return 0;
        elseif ($a < $b) return 1;
        else return -1;
    });

    // now display the posts...
    foreach($posts as $post) {
```

Comment: done J Richard Snape.

Comment: @j-richard-snape any reason you deleted your comment? For posterity, my comment above was in answer to J Richard Snape's request to show my current code.

Comment: When you say the meta value is stored as an array of user ids, do you mean like this `1,2,3,4`? Please add an example of the value stored in a meta field for a post.

Comment: It's a serialised array, e.g. a:4:{i:0;s:4:"1714";i:1;i:1333;i:2;i:1332;i:3;s:2:"38";}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure how you store the number of likes in your database. If you store the data as an comma separated string `<userid>,<userid>,<userid>` you could write a query like this to order your posts by the number of likes:

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, 
                             post_title, 
                             LENGTH(m.meta_value) -  
                             LENGTH(REPLACE(m.meta_value, ',', '')) + 1 likes 
                             FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
                             LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} m ON m.post_ID = p.ID &&
                                                         m.meta_key = 'likes' 
                             ORDER BY likes DESC", OBJECT);
```

The above calculates the number of likes by subtracting the length of the `meta_value` with the length of the `meta_value` without commas and then adding 1.

You should be able to use the same technique in cases where your meta value contains a serialized array. Notice that each value need to be stored as a string for this to work:

```
// serialized array of user ids
a:4:{i:0;s:4:"1714";i:1;s:4:"1333";i:2;s:4:"1332";i:3;s:2:"38";}

$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, 
                             post_title, 
                             (LENGTH(m.meta_value) -  
                             LENGTH(REPLACE(m.meta_value, '\"', '')) - 2) * 0.5 likes 
                             FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
                             LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} m ON m.post_ID = p.ID &&
                                                         m.meta_key = 'likes' 
                             ORDER BY likes DESC", OBJECT);
```

Comment: it's a serialised array, e.g. a:4:{i:0;s:4:"1714";i:1;i:1333;i:2;i:1332;i:3;s:2:"38";}

Comment: so really what we want is the number immediately after the first ":" (colon).

Comment: @Seano - I made an update that should work as long as each user id is stored as a serialized string. In your above example it seems like you're mixing both integers and strings when storing your data.

Comment: Thanks Cyclone. You're right, I think my arrays are all broken. The one I posted above seems to have indices without size fields. Since your answer has been the most helpful, I'm accepting it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am making a liking plugin for wordpress and ran into this same issue. I ended up approaching it as you explained in a comment which was to just get the number after the first 'a:' in the serialized array. To do this, I used the mysql SUBSTR function.

```
SELECT ID, post_title, SUBSTR(m.meta_value,3,1) likes 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} m ON m.post_ID = p.ID && m.meta_key = 'likes' 
ORDER BY likes DESC
```